# Laravel 5.3 validation erros message not showed

Tags: validation, laravel-5.3

I got a simple validation rule list:

```
$rules = [
        'vehicle_id'=> 'required|exists:vehicles,id',
        'ztl_id'=> 'required|exists:ztls,id',
        'user_id' => 'required|exists:users,id',
        'inizio' => 'required|date',
        'fine' => 'required|date|after:inizio',
        'percorso'=> 'required'
    ];
    $validator = $this->validate($request, $rules);
    dd("not until here");
```

If run this code over my controller a general error is raised (in case of validation fails), something like: `"validation as fail"` with nothing more inside!

But travelling trough classes Ive found that in the method:

```
 public function validate(Request $request, array $rules, array $messages = [], array $customAttributes = [])
    {
        $validator = $this->getValidationFactory()->make($request->all(), $rules, $messages, $customAttributes);

        if ($validator->fails()) {

            dd($validator->errors()->getMessages());

            $this->throwValidationException($request, $validator);
        }
    }
```

of `ValidateRequest`

the             `dd($validator->errors()->getMessages());`
 shows:

> array:3 
>   [   "inizio" => array:1 
>   [
>       0 => "The inizio field is required."   ]
>   "fine" => array:1 [
>       0 => "The fine field is required."   ]
>   "percorso" => array:1 [
>       0 => "The percorso field is required."   ] ]

thats are all my errors, so why `throwValidationException($request, $validator);` showed just a general fails instead of the correct mexs?

Comment: even if I put `try {
            $validator = $this->validate($request, $rules);

        }
        catch(\Exception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }`  same general error